# How do I manipulate bits in Python?

Tags: python

In C I could, for example, zero out bit #10 in a 32 bit unsigned value like so:

```
unsigned long value = 0xdeadbeef;
value &= ~(1<<10);
```

How do I do that in Python ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Bitwise operations on Python ints work much like in C. The `&`, `|` and `^` operators in Python work just like in C. The `~` operator works as for a signed integer in C; that is, `~x` computes `-x-1`.

You have to be somewhat careful with left shifts, since Python integers aren't fixed-width. Use bit masks to obtain the low order bits. For example, to do the equivalent of shift of a 32-bit integer do `(x << 5) & 0xffffffff`.

Answer (score 17):

```
value = 0xdeadbeef
value &= ~(1<<10)
```

Answer (score 13):

Some common bit operations that might serve as example:

```
def get_bit(value, n):
    return ((value >> n & 1) != 0)

def set_bit(value, n):
    return value | (1 << n)

def clear_bit(value, n):
    return value & ~(1 << n)
```

Usage e.g.

```
>>> get_bit(5, 2)
True
>>> get_bit(5, 1)
False
>>> set_bit(5, 1)
7
>>> clear_bit(5, 2)
1 
>>> clear_bit(7, 2)
3
```

Answer (score 5):

Python has C style bit manipulation operators, so your example is literally the same in Python except without type keywords.

```
value = 0xdeadbeef
value &= ~(1 << 10)
```

Answer (score 5):

You should also check out [BitArray](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/0.2.3), which is a nice interface for dealing with sequences of bits.

Answer (score 4):

Omit the 'unsigned long', and the semi-colons are not needed either:

```
value = 0xDEADBEEF
value &= ~(1<<10)
print value
"0x%08X" % value
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried copying and pasting your code into the Python REPL to see what will happen?

```
>>> value = 0xdeadbeef
>>> value &= ~(1<<10)
>>> hex (value)
'0xdeadbaef'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to do a lot of bit manipulation ( and you care much more about readability rather than performance for your application ) then you may want to create an integer wrapper to enable slicing like in Verilog or VHDL:

```
 import math
 class BitVector:
     def __init__(self,val):
         self._val = val

     def __setslice__(self,highIndx,lowIndx,newVal):
         assert math.ceil(math.log(newVal)/math.log(2)) <= (highIndx-lowIndx+1)

         # clear out bit slice
         clean_mask = (2**(highIndx+1)-1)^(2**(lowIndx)-1)

         self._val = self._val ^ (self._val & clean_mask)
         # set new value
         self._val = self._val | (newVal<<lowIndx)

     def __getslice__(self,highIndx,lowIndx):
         return (self._val>>lowIndx)&(2L**(highIndx-lowIndx+1)-1)

 b = BitVector(0)
 b[3:0]   = 0xD
 b[7:4]   = 0xE
 b[11:8]  = 0xA
 b[15:12] = 0xD

 for i in xrange(0,16,4):
     print '%X'%b[i+3:i]
```

Outputs:

```
 D
 E
 A
 D
```

Comment: Great solution! You might consider adding it as `pip` package. However, just to note, that it works only with Python 2. (which makes sense, since it's more than 10 years old...)

Answer (score 3):

```
a = int('00001111', 2)
b = int('11110000', 2)
bin(a & b)[2:].zfill(8)
bin(a | b)[2:].zfill(8)
bin(a << 2)[2:].zfill(8)
bin(a >> 2)[2:].zfill(8)
bin(a ^ b)[2:].zfill(8)
int(bin(a | b)[2:].zfill(8), 2)
```