# How do you do bit operation in Python?

Tags: python, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I manipulate bits in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147713/how-do-i-manipulate-bits-in-python)

Here is my code:

```
int val = 0xAA;
int Bit, i;

for (i = 0; i < sizeof(Val)*8; i++) {
    Bit = 1<<i;    
    if (Val & Bit) {
        printf("Found a bit \n");
    }
}
```

I am a C person and I need to do this in Python. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Mostly you can just use the same operators.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147713/how-do-i-manipulate-bits-in-python Similar question.

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation, you do them the same way you could in C:

[5.4.1 Bitwise Operations on Integer Types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types)

Answer (score 0):

The same as C, as **Justin** said below.

If you're really having trouble, you can learn pretty easily [here](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-intermediate-en-KE1UJ?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096).

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much the same as C, except in C the types are fixed (16 bit, 32 bit etc... - in Python they're able to scale as much as needs be, so fundamentally, it's the same, but would be better written as):

```
for i in range(val.bit_length()):
    if val & (1 << i):
        print 'found a bit'
```

You could also just do,

```
>>> format(val, 'b')
'10101010'
```

To get it as a bitstring as well depending exactly what you're after.

Comment: val = 0xaa
bitvalue = format(val, 'b')
for bit in bitvalue:
    if (bit=='1'):
        print bit

Comment: @SanthoshKumar well - if you wanted, but no reason to not use the normal bitwise ops - it was just an example