# Bit manipulate clarification in Python

Tags: python, python-3.5

Hi I'm referring to following link
[How do I manipulate bits in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147713/how-do-i-manipulate-bits-in-python/35786902#35786902)
If I execute the last responded answer code I get below error.
Here is the code snippet for quick reference

```
import math
class BitVector:
      def __init__(self,val):
         self._val = val

      def __setslice__(self,highIndx,lowIndx,newVal):
         assert math.ceil(math.log(newVal)/math.log(2)) <= (highIndx-lowIndx+1)

         # clear out bit slice
         clean_mask = (2**(highIndx+1)-1)^(2**(lowIndx)-1)

         self._val = self._val ^ (self._val & clean_mask)
         # set new value
         self._val = self._val | (newVal<<lowIndx)
     def __getslice__(self,highIndx,lowIndx):
         return (self._val>>lowIndx)&(2L**(highIndx-lowIndx+1)-1) ## Error in the code I think it is not 2L.
b = BitVector(0)
b[3:0]   = 0xD
b[7:4]   = 0xE
b[11:8]  = 0xA
b[15:12] = 0xD

for i in xrange(0,16,4):
    print '%X'%b[i+3:i]
```

After fixing error(2L change to 2**) in the above code I get below error

When I try to execute the above code I get following error Traceback (most recent call last): File "BitVector.py", line 20, in b[3:0] = 0xD TypeError: 'BitVector' object does not support item assignment

Comment: The part you say you "fixed" actually looks fine, at least for Python 2, and the error message you posted doesn't look like it has anything to do with any of the code you posted.

Comment: What Python version are you using?  That code works fine for me, taken directly with copy & paste into Python 2.7.  After I remove the **L**, it still works.

Comment: Now, please correct the posting.  This question should stand on its own.  Supply the full code to reproduce the problem, and the entire error message.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5 version. I copy pasted full code and ran I get above error.

Answer (score 1):

`__setslice__` and `__getslice__` have been deprecated since Python2.6 and [removed in Python3.5](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.__setslice__).
Use `__setitem__` and `__getitem__` instead:

```
import math

class BitVector:
    """
    http://stackoverflow.com/a/150411/190597 (Ross Rogers)
    Updated for Python3
    """
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._val = val

    def __setitem__(self, item, newVal):
        highIndx, lowIndx = item.start, item.stop
        assert math.ceil(
            math.log(newVal) / math.log(2)) <= (highIndx - lowIndx + 1)

        # clear out bit slice
        clean_mask = (2 ** (highIndx + 1) - 1) ^ (2 ** (lowIndx) - 1)

        self._val = self._val ^ (self._val & clean_mask)
        # set new value
        self._val = self._val | (newVal << lowIndx)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        highIndx, lowIndx = item.start, item.stop
        return (self._val >> lowIndx) & (2 ** (highIndx - lowIndx + 1) - 1)

b = BitVector(0)
b[3:0] = 0xD
b[7:4] = 0xE
b[11:8] = 0xA
b[15:12] = 0xD

for i in range(0, 16, 4):
    print('%X' % b[i + 3:i])
```

prints

```
D
E
A
D
```

Comment: Thank you now it worked. Looks like xrange is deprecated in Python3.5 I have changed xrange to range and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Yes, `xrange` was also removed in Python3, and `print` was made a function instead of a statement (and therefore requires parentheses to call the function).